# need help to place a verable within a python webbrowser.open

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code

`text = pic.image_to_string(image)`

`webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/search?q='(text))`

i need to place the variable **test** in url so i can look up every image text scanned

Comment: edit your question so it makes sense. Name the stuff in code and text the same

Answer (score 0):

Using f-strings, for Python >= 3.6

`webbrowser.open(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={text}')`

Using format

`webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/search?q={}'.format(text))`